# I set a password on my PS Vita, and my brother somehow restored my data (meaning he deleted it). Can I get it back?

Tags: ps-vita

So, basically, I set a password on my PS Vita and my brother decides to mess around with it. I don't know how, but he somehow restored the Vita, which means all data and settings are deleted and set to original settings.

It's a factory reset, basically.

I did a little investigating, and here's what I came up with.

I don't think that it reset the Memory Card. I have one, but it doesn't say that it would, but even if it did, whenever I put the Memory Card in after taking it out, it says that a Playstation account is linked to it, and it asks me if I want to link it.

Yes, it's my account. But the weird thing is, it detects the Memory Card externally, but not internally, with the settings. So it detects when I take it out, meaning it shows notifications, but when I click the following in settings...

"Playstation®Mobile"

It says...

"No memory card is inserted."

So I'm confused.

I've tried to get to Safe Mode a couple times, it doesn't bring me there.

My question, obviously, is how to get my data back. I am fairly sure I still have the data on my memory card, and the external system detects it, but Content Manager, Settings, etc. don't. So how?!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to games but to hardware and playstation account management.

Comment: @user1337 - Questions about hardware and account management for gaming-specific software (and online services like PSN) are perfectly on topic for Arqade

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'm going to answer this in two parts.

On the point of recovering you game data. It's possible that the memory card still has your data on it if he didn't perform a system format on the reset. If he did then that data is gone. If you sign into your PSN account and activate the system you should be able to view the contents of the card. Very likely though if you have signed into your Vita with your PSN account and it's not recognizing the content on the card then it is blank, or was reset to a new account which can't be accessed from your PSN credentials.

Now to the comment you made about "Playstation®Mobile". Regardless of the situation with your system, for this class of games you are completely out of luck. You can not reinstall them and even if they are present on the memory card you can not reactivate them because Sony disabled the activation servers for Playstation Mobile services several years ago. At this point those games are only playble for users who installed and activated before the server turn off. Even if you restore from a backup, the games will need reactivated and that's not possible anymore.